# Is there a way I can refactor this Generic class to avoid where constraints all over my C# code?

Tags: c#, generics, constraints

I currently have a generic interface and a generic type, `ISignal<T>` and `SignalValue<T>` respectively. However, I have a constraint on `<T>` for SignalValue that requires T to be comparable.

A simplified version of each looks as follows:

```
public interface ISignal<T> where T : IComparable
{
    string FullName { get; }
    public void SetValue(SignalValue<T> value, bool withLog = true);
    public SignalValue<T> GetValue(int readDelayMs = 500);
}

public class SignalValue<T> : IEquatable<T>, IComparable<T>, IComparable, ISignalValue where T : IComparable
{
    public readonly T Value;

    public SignalValue(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public virtual int CompareTo(T other)
    {
       return Value.CompareTo(other);
    }
}
```

`SignalValue<T>` is mostly used as a wrapper for a value where T is a bool or double with some additional properties tied to it. However, as soon as I have this constraint, I am finding due to boxing that the constraint is propagating everywhere. For instance, I have the following static method which obviously needs the constraint as well even though it has no real dependency on anything comparison related:

```
public static void DoSequence<T>(ISignal<T> signal, List<SequencePair<T>> pair) where T : IComparable
{
      if (signal == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(signal));
      if (pair == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pair));
            
      if (pair.Count <= 0) return;

       List<SequencePair<T>> orderedList = pair.OrderBy(p => p.Seconds).ToList();
       //... more stuff but no comparison at all
 }
```

I understand why this constraint is needed but it is also making me wonder if setting this up with a constraint on the generic type within my class is a code smell. Is there some way I can still make my class require a comparable type without requiring constraints throughout my code wherever a `SignalValue<T>` is used?

Comment: _"I understand why this constraint is needed"_ -- then you also understand why you need to provide the constraint everywhere you use `SignalValue<T>`. How is the compiler supposed to verify that your type parameter is legal for use with `SignalValue<T>`, if you don't also provide the constraint. What makes you think you should be able to get away with that?

Comment: I don't think I should be able to get away with it -- which is why the second part of the sentence says "... wonder if setting this up with a constraint on the generic type within my class is a code smell" which is implying I'd like to know if there is a better way. Maybe I should have been more generic and just asked "is there a better way." I do that in the last sentence, but I suppose I'm overly specific in asking if the class can require the type. Regardless, @JonasH answers this below.

Comment: If `DoSequence` is a static method inside `SignalValue<T>` then you don't need to redeclare `T`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most circumstances, generic constraints can be replaced by delegation to to some other type. For comparisons that would be [`IComparer<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icomparer-1?view=net-5.0). So if your method requires comparisons, you can add a IComparer parameter. For convenience, you can also add overload with a generic constraint and uses a `Comparer<T>.Default` and delegate implementation to the main method.

Most methods that does anything related to sorting can take a IComparer object, and this is in general a more flexible solution than implementing IComparable, since there can only be one IComparable implementation.

In your example, `SignalValue<T>` has a public `Value`, so there is no real need for a `CompareTo` method. Anyone that wants to compare the value can just do `mySignalValue.Value.CompareTo(myOtherSignalValue.Value)`, no real need to implement IComparable.